# React, Flux, Root component

Tags: javascript, architecture, reactjs, flux

In not one page applications I'd like to have several components like 'Filter', 'LoginForm' etc, and I have large enough markup, so,
I'd like to have some dependencies between components, how could I implement it without Root component (I dont want to put main markup to it)?

My first thought to user flux's dispatcher and stores, is it viable and right way?

For now, what I found in documentation:

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you provide some "ideal" code and why it doesn't work as written?

Comment: I'm newby in react, maybe it is better to ask: "How can I get the state of other component without mutual parent component?".

Comment: ^^ if you have a central data store (flux, redux) that both components have access to, they can get the data from there instead of a shared parent component

Comment: Agree with @Dylan, however I'm not sure why you're avoiding a Root component. Passing data through props is almost always the preferred way. What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Good point @JoshDavidMiller, I'll usually have the route handler components connect to redux, and pass data down from there, unless there are distinct boundaries in the UI that have separate data concerns then I may have more than one connected component.

Comment: Thx a lot, I've done it with flux!

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I want to avoid the root component because I dont want to pass all my template to root's component templates because I'd like to show it to search engine.

Comment: @user1871941 I didn't follow that at all. If you're worried about SEO, the Google indexer/crawler will render react components. But anyway, glad you got it working!

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Thank you, we need to work with yandex.ru also and it works correctly with js not for sure. =)

Comment: Can anybody here explain to me what a root component is?

I know this is a separate question, but it was mentioned...